# Can someone help me obtain these a-priori estimates?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, bochner-spaces, parabolic-pde

I am trying to obtain some estimates on a PDE where the unknown is:

$u(t) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, t \in [0,T]$.

The variational formulation is given below, where the test function is set to $\phi = u(t)$ :

$\epsilon^2 ||D(u(t))||^2_{L^2(\Omega_1)^{n^2}} + \int_0^t ||D(u(t'))||^2_{L^2(\Omega_2)^{n^2}} dt' = \int_0^t \int_\Omega F u dxdt $

$\epsilon$ is a small paramter, $D(\cdot)$ is the symmetric gradient, and $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$. $F(x,t)$ is a known function and whatever regularity is needed for it can be assumed.

It should be possible to get the following estimates on $u$ from the above (the constant $C$ depends on $F$ but not on $\epsilon$):

(1) $||D(u)||_{L^\infty(0,T; L^2(\Omega_1)^{n^2})} \leq \epsilon^{-1}C$

(2) $||u||_{L^\infty(0,T; L^2(\Omega_1)^{n})} \leq C$

(3) $||D(u)||_{L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega_2)^{n^2})} \leq C$

(4) $||u||_{L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega_2)^{n})} \leq C$

I am able to obtain the estimate (1) by writing the RHS as: $\int_0^t \int_{\Omega_1} F u dxdt + \int_0^t \int_{\Omega_2} F u dxdt$, and then using the Cauchy-Shwartz and Young inequalities to absorb the $\Omega_2$-term on the LHS, and then using Gronwalls inequality. However, I fail to see how the rest of the estimates should be obtained.

If anything is unclear please ask.

Comment: What is the pde? What is the variational formulation - which needs a test function?

Comment: My question is really just "how do you get the estimates (1)-(4) from the equation above". Maybe I just made it more confusing by talking about the variational form. I think all the relevant information should be there though